# Rails logging in Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, passenger

What kind of information should I expect to see in production.log from a default production environment in rails 3.2?

I'm running Passenger and have tried accessing made up controller names and invalid parameters, but nothing is showing up in production.log.

I tried setting the logger level to debug in environments/production.rb, but that log is still blank.

Thanks

### Edit

Here's more info on the flushing issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277

Comment: I'm experiencing the same recently. Rails 3.2.1 + latest passenger.

Comment: It is fixed in the (currently) latest 3.2.11 for sure. In my case it's usually that after the Capistrano deploy, the Apache Passenger doesn't have any rights to write to `log/` so `chmod -R 0777 current/log` to the rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's because of logfile flushing. By default rails not flushing every write to log in production environment.

[This](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4998) pull request fix it, and in rails HEAD you can try

```
config.autoflush_log = true
```

Comment: where is that line? Production.rb?

Comment: Well, yes, in your desired environment file in config/environments

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set `Rails.logger` to `ActiveSupport::Logger` by creating an initializer.

Check the value by `Rails.logger` if it shows `<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:`  change it to active support.

```
config/initializer/logger.rb 

Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

EDIT: I tried doing the same in `production.rb` using `config.logger` but it always gets overwritten. So i decided to go with this approach.